# How to populate a TreeView made in resource script

Tags: c++, treeview, items, vspackage

I have to make a C++, VSPackage that contains a TreeView. I added one in the default dialog window of the project resource script (*.rc) from the toolbox window. The problem is that I don't know how to add items to it.

I looked on many websites but they have code for C# or other types of projects.

I found a project made by Song Ho Ahn and also the source code that can be found at the bottom of this website [TreeView](http://www.songho.ca/misc/treeview/treeview.html).

I tried to go to the TreeView properties window to see if there is something so I can add items to it and then finding a way to replace them, but nothing. I tried to use the code he written just to help me find a solution to my problem, but I couldn't find it. Maybe it's the "handler" and the "parent", which I don't know how to use.

```
void set(HWND parent, int id, bool visible=true) 
    { 
        this->parent = parent;
        handle = GetDlgItem(parent, id);
        if(!visible) disable(); 
    }
```

I want to mention that I'm a beginner with VSPackage and that I didn't made a project this big before.

If somebody can explain to me what to do, send me on a path or even say that I'm stupid and the solution is a simple one, I will appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snippet you've posted, you're using native WIN32 API. So you might look into the documentation of [TVM_INSERTITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb773733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Here is a little snippet to add a single entry to a TreeView control (regardless if created by a resource script or a call of CreateWindow(..)):

```
TVITEM tvi; 
TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins;
HTREEITEM hItem;

/* setup new item */
tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT;   // just text 
tvi.pszText = "Hello TreeView!";
tvi.cchTextMax = 0;    // ignored if creating the item

/* setup insertion structure of item */
tvins.hParent = TVI_ROOT;    // insert item at root level
tvins.item = tvi;            // item description setup above
tvins.hInsertAfter = NULL;   // instert on top of the tree view
hItem = (HTREEITEM)SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_TREEVIEW),   // update parameters of GetDlgItem(..) according to your code
                               TVM_INSERTITEM,
                               0,
                               (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT)&tvins);
if (hItem == NULL)
{
   /* something went wrong */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got 2 problems, and managed to solve only 1. The problem that I solved is that I couldn't use the code sample you provided in "MyToolWindow.h" and had to make a new Header file for it ( simple solution ). The second problem is that I tried to  give the "GerDlgItem" to an other variable like ' HWND hItemWnd = GetDlgItem(hWndCtl, IDC_RESULTS_TREE); '. The problem is that "hItemWnd" doesen't change ( seen in debug ). Isn't an other way that doesn't use "GetDlgItem" ? Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: The function GetDlgItem(..) returns a handle to the child window with the given id. So therefore the HWND must be that of the window containing the TreeView. If GetDlgItem(..) returns NULL an error occurred (usually wrong input data, especially wrong HWND).Could you provide some more code? It's a little difficult to "imagine" you problem... ;-)

Comment: The problem is that it's a big VSPackage so I can only give you the code for the Tools Window and the code I use from mr. Song Ho Ahn website. You can download the files from here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/crx3xjck1886ys0/AABQXHGi9_L0XmjbmQleCZqpa?dl=0) . If you want I can grant you Read Access on BitBucket.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see why your code isn't working! My only guess is that in function OnSearchButtonClick (MyToolWindow.h) the hWndCtl is the handle of the control clicked. Therefore it will no contain the TreeView you are trying to insert items. So you need to have the handle of your toolwindow. Try the following: treeView.set(::GetParent(hWndCtl), IDC_RESULTS_TREE);

Comment: Thank you very much :) You are a life saver. '::GetParent(hWndCtl)' is the solution of my problem. Before I asked here for help I tried to add in MyToolWindow.h, in "Begin_Msg_Map" the following command 'COMMAND_HANDLER(IDC_RESULTS_TREE, NM_CUSTOMDRAW, OnTreeViewEvent)', but the truth is that for the moment I don't know how to call OnTreeViewEvent in other methods or commands like 'OnSearchButtonClick'. Now I will try to solve my other problems. Thank you very much again and I wish you a good day. :)